# No ParameterResolver registered for parameter XXXX in constructor Junit5 java

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit5

Trying to perform simple JUnit 5 testing as below

```
@Singleton
        record Repository(MongoClient mongoClient, MongodbConfiguration mongodbConfiguration) implements IRepository {
    @Override
    public <T> MongoCollection<T> getCollection(String collectionName, Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        return mongoClient
                .getDatabase(mongodbConfiguration.database())
                .getCollection(collectionName, typeParameterClass);
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface IRepository {
    <T> MongoCollection<T> getCollection(String collectionName, Class<T> typeParameterClass);
}
```

**Unit testing**

```
public record RepositoryTest(IRepository iRepository) {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should return product collection")
    void shouldReturnProductCollection() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [fete.bird.repository.IRepository iRepository] in constructor [public fete.bird.RepositoryTest(fete.bird.repository.IRepository)].
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [fete.bird.repository.IRepository iRepository] in constructor [public fete.bird.RepositoryTest(fete.bird.repository.IRepository)].
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:200)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:183)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:135)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

**Gradle configuration**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'fete.bird'
version '0.1'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    implementation("fete.bird:common:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
    implementation 'io.micronaut.mongodb:micronaut-mongo-reactive:3.1.0'

    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject:2.5.4"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:2.5.4"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:2.5.4"

    testImplementation project(':domain')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    jvmArgs(['--enable-preview'])
}
```

Comment: you should not pass `IRepository iRepository` to the test class constructor, though. imho, you are also abusing `record`s in this manner.

Comment: I have a dependency on that interface IRepository iRepository. I need it but right now I was doing simple assertion.

Comment: sorry I did not get your point with "I have a dependency on that interface IRepository iRepository." the problem is that you pass `iRepository` to the test class constructor (which is a `record`) via that `public record RepositoryTest(IRepository iRepository)`

Comment: I have to make dependency injection for that interface. For current situation I am not implementing any method, but later I have to implement some methods

Comment: so what stops you to create an instance of that `Repository` with (potentially) mocked `MongoClient mongoClient, MongodbConfiguration mongodbConfiguration` _inside_ your test method or a `private final` field at the class level? junit-5 does not know where to take that `iRepository`, because it comes as a constructor argument. do I make sense?

Comment: JUnit creates an instance of your test class. Your test class has a parameter in its constructor, and JUnit does not know how to resolve an appropriate argument. You need to tell it how to do this by adding a `ParameterResolver` extension (either coded by you or provided by whatever DI framework you're using). Or you can remove the constructor parameter and initialize the `IRepository` yourself (e.g. inline with a field or even using `@BeforeAll` / `@BeforeEach`).

Comment: I wonder if the thing that you miss is that `public record RepositoryTest(IRepository iRepository)` will create a `.class` file _with_ a constructor that takes `IRepostiory` as an argument?

Comment: @Eugene Yeah it makes sense to me, can you please tell me how can I Mock the mongoCLient and mongodbConfiguration

Comment: this goes beyond the scope of the question, but it is as simple as `MongoClient mockClient = Mockito.mock(MongoClient.class)` and the same thing for the other argument

Comment: @Eugene mate can you please post one sample code

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `record` for the test, imo. You could simply do:

```
public class RepositoryTest {

    private final MongoClient mockClient = Mockito.mock(MongoClient.class);
    private final MongodbConfiguration mockConfiguration = Mockito.mock(MongodbConfiguration.class);

    private final Repository repo = new Repository(mockClient, mockConfiguration);

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should return product collection")
    void shouldReturnProductCollection() {
       // set expectation for the mocks, your "homework" here
       MongoCollection<YouClassHere>  result = repo.getCollection("name", SomeClassHere);
       // assertions on the result, your "homework" here again
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have an interface as IRepository I was thinking to use this interface instead of creating the instance directly

Comment: @SanJaisy it seems you are very confused on how Spring works or unit testing in general. Sorry, but this is as far as I'll go here

Comment: I am using Micronaut, sorry for my inconvenience, trying to use the micronaut dependency injectionon

Comment: @SanJaisy Maybe [this](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/#junit5) can help?

Comment: @Slaw spot-on! I assumed `Spring` for I have no idea what reason